# Copying and modifying a file to incorporate additional data

Tags: perl

I am novel to Perl and I am still in the exploring/beginners stage.

I have a text file that is built up as follows:

```
Naam;ISIN;Symbol;Market;Trading Currency\n
IDI;FR0000051393;IDIP;Euronext Paris;EUR\n
BETER BED;NL0000339703;BBED;Euronext Amsterdam;EUR\n
ALCATEL-LUCENT;FR0000130007;ALU;Euronext Paris;EUR\n
FIPP;FR0000038184;FIPP;Euronext Paris;EUR\n
...
```

With the following code, I manage to read the text file in the hashes/lists.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %data;
my @names;

my $myFile = "myfile.csv";
open(FH, '<', $myFile) or error("Cannot open file ($!)");

while (<FH>) {
    chomp;
    my @list = split(';');
    for (my $i = 0; $i <= $#list; $i++) {
        if ($. == 1) {
            $names[$i] = $list[$i];
        } else {
            push @{$data{$names[$i]}}, $list[$i];
        }
    }
}
close FH;
```

I have the following two questions.

1. I wish to create an additional column (hash/list) called `Ticker`, which does roughly the following:

   ```
   if ($Market eq "Euronext Paris") {
       $Symbol = "$Symbol.PA";
       {print "$Symbol\n"};
   } elsif ($Market eq "Euronext Brussels") {
       $Symbol = "$Symbol.BR";
       {print "$Symbol\n"};
   }
   ```

   and so on for the other markets. (Note the above code worked when I read the file into an array, however, but I find it difficult to modify to the hases/lists compatible syntax.)
2. How can I export the columns: Name, Symbol, Market and Ticker to a tab delimited text file?

Comment: https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV#SYNOPSIS if you want some actual work to be done.

Comment: Would be much better create an Array of Hashes (e.g. each element of the array is a hash with the row values, as one Hash of Arrays... The above linked module should greatly helps...

Comment: `Data::Dumper` (or one of the newer successors available on the CPAN, such as `Data::Dump` or `Data::Dumper::Streamer`) is very helpful when working with complex data structures.

Comment: Could you help with some examples.   Unfortunately, I am rather novel to Perl.   BTW, I am running perl on a Mac with X11 installed -- I suppose this is not an issue.

Comment: Th text file will serve as an input file for another program.  Basically, the text file is updated on a daily basis and tells the other program what stocks need to be included in the analysis.

Comment: All shares have a ticker.  Which is unique identifier on a market, e.g. Euronext Amsterdam.

Comment: Where did you get the `error` function? It is not a built-in one. Should be `die` probably.

Comment: The symbol HAL is refers to the company Hal Trust on the  Euronext Amsterdam, but HAL on the NYSE is Halliburton.   For this reason, AS is appended to the Symbol HAL, making HAL.AS.   HAL.AS is the yahoo finance ticker and on this basis automated share prices can be downloaded, analysed, ...

Comment: You incorrectly refer to arrays as lists. These two are completely different concepts. Arrays have the `@` sigil and are indexed via square brackets (`[]`). Lists are abstract, have no storage (can be stored as an array or hash), have no sigil, …

Comment: @Palec The OP is a Perl newbie. I think your comments will be going straight over their head.

Comment: @ialarmedalien I think knowing that there is a difference between lists and arrays is crucial for being able to read Perl manual. Wrong terminology leads to misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're doing a fairly simple transformation on your input file, the best best is to read your input file and create your output file at the same time. I've adapted your script to do this, and have put comments throughout the code on what is going on. Please ask if you don't understand what the script is doing.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

# here are some tickers (including some I made up)
# initialise these at the top of your script in a hash
# if you want to get the abbreviation for, say, 'Euronext Roma',
# you access it using $tickers{'Euronext Roma'}
my %tickers = (
    'Euronext Paris' => 'PA',
    'Euronext Brussels' => 'BR',
    'Euronext Madrid' => 'MA',
    'Euronext Roma' => 'RO'
);

# set up the input file
my $infile = "myfile.csv";
open my $in, '<', $infile or die "Cannot open file $infile: $!";

# this will be our output
my $outfile = 'stocks_with_tickers.txt';
open my $out, '>', $outfile or die "Cannot open file $outfile: $!";

# print out the column headers for the new file
# the function join takes a separator as its first argument,
# and joins the array of variables following it with that separator
print { $out } join "\t", "Name", "Symbol", "Market", "Ticker\n";

# input file format:
# Naam;ISIN;Symbol;Market;Trading Currency
# when we split the line to form an array, we will want the values
# in array positions 0, 2, 3 (the first array position is 0 in Perl)

# output file format:
# Name; Symbol; Market; Ticker
# we get the ticker by looking for $tickers{ MARKET }
#

while (<$in>){
    # skip the line unless it contains some alphanumeric characters
    next unless /\w+/;
    # $. is the number of the line that we are on.
    # Skip the first line of the file (the header row)
    if ($. == 1) {
        next;
    }

    # split up the line
    my @list = split ";";
    # print cols 0, 2, 3 to the output
    # note that the braces around $out ( i.e. { $out } ) are to make it
    # clearer that $out is the file that you're printing the results in
    print { $out } join "\t", $list[0], $list[2], $list[3],

    # we're going to use the ternary form of if/else, which allows
    # us to do an in/else test within the print statement
    # this line tests if $tickers{ MARKET } exists
    ( exists $tickers{ $list[3] } )
    # if it does, print out the market symbol plus the ticker abbrev
    ? $list[2] . "." . $tickers{$list[3]} . "\n"
    # otherwise, leave it blank
    : "\n";
}
close $in;
close $out;
# we're done!
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.   I am studying this code with great interest.   It is a great help to familiarize myself with the Perl jargon.

Comment: @GaMmeeu Sorry that it didn't use any hashes (well, apart from `%tickers`!), but I'm sure there will be future problems to solve that will require hashes. If you have any questions, just ask. If the answer was helpful, please click the tick and/or upvote it to show that.

Comment: I have spent quite some time studying the code today.  In fact great fun immersing myself into this.   Good learning experience.  I am starting to understand about Perl.

Comment: In order to get the code to work, I needed to change <DATA> in the while line to <FH> and the opening of the output file to the following: open ( my $fout, '>', $out) or die "Cannot open file $out: $!";   In fact this part is still puzzling me.

Comment: Ah - that is a typo! I've edited the code so it should be correct now. When you say `open (OUT, '>', $outfile) or die "cannot open file $outfile: $!;`, you can use a variable instead of `OUT` (and the same goes for `FH` for your input file).

Comment: Exact that is precisely what it puzzling me.   The following is the error message I get:   Name "main::OUT" used only once: possible typo at ./myEuronext.pl line 30.
Can't use string ("out.txt") as a symbol ref while "strict refs" in use at ./myEuronext.pl line 35.
Commenting out use strict;  is a workaround or the solution with my $fout given above.   Puzzling ...   I am searching for a type somewhere, but I have not spotted it yet.

Comment: It is better to use a variable instead of `OUT` or `FH` ([more info on that](http://eev.ee/blog/2011/04/13/perl-worst-practices/#two-argument-open)) -- I have edited the script so both the input and output use variables. Have a look at it now and see if it is clearer. I didn't want to change too much of your original code, but it ended up being more confusing with the two different ways to refer to filehandles!